# PHP removes milliseconds (seconds decimals) from timestamp column

Tags: php, mysql, request

My DB has three columns, which are id, seconds (a timestamp) and values (a float). When I send "SELECT * FROM lin_m4 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", where lin_m4 is the name of the table, the milliseconds returned value of the seconds column are removed.

Here is a tipical row of my DB (note that the names are written in Spanish):

`( id, segundos, valor) -> '145788', '2021-06-17 15:43:15.825', '-0.15469'`

And here is what I get after a request (in JSON format):

`[{"id":145788,"segundos":"2021-06-17 15:43:15","valor":-0.15469}]`.

My code in PHP is:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="something";
$dbname="somethingelse";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
}

$sql='SELECT * FROM lin_m4 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$outpf = json_encode($outp);
echo $outpf;
$conn->close();
?>
```

I want to know how to prevent the milliseconds from being dropped when I make a request.

Comment: What type is the "segundos" column?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? It seems like you are using some ancient PHP version